# Magento prices with and without vat

Tags: price, vat

I would like to have in my pages prices shown with and without vat.
I set up that it shows both prices, but no matter what I do prices are always same.
Check:

> http://www.pro-orodje.si/montirke-centrirke/centrirni-stroji/avtomatski-centrirni-stroj-casb96an.html

- with vat: 915€
- without vat: 915€

915€ is price including vat.
When I go to manage products-prices I have there a window where I put price inside it says:
Price *    915
              [EUR] [Inc. Tax]

What can I do to have different prices, so price with or without vat?

Comment: can you please tell us which magento?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.3

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$taxClassId = $_product->getData("tax_class_id");
$taxClasses = Mage::helper("core")->jsonDecode(Mage::helper("tax")->getAllRatesByProductClass());
$taxRate = $taxClasses["value_".$taxClassId];
$price_with_tax = $_product->getPrice();

$divided_value = 1+($taxRate/100);
$price_without_tax = $price_with_tax/$divided_value;
$price_without_tax_formatted = Mage::helper('core')->currency($price_without_tax, true, false);
echo $price_without_tax_formatted." exc GST";

?>
```

Comment: this code will get you price without TAX

Comment: I need on my page price with and without vat. Because of law in Slovenia, I need to have both of them shown.   I copy this to main folder?